# need to find an external database's prefix

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I'm creating a plugin for WordPress and part of the plugin requires that I connect to an external WordPress site and use that site's external database to get some information. I have established a connection and I have accessed the external database's `$wpdb` using the code below:

```
global $new_wpdb;

define( 'BLOCK_LOAD', true ); 
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' ); 
require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php' ); 
$new_wpdb = new wpdb( $username, $password, $dbname, $servername); 
$new_wpdb->show_errors();
```

When I use `print_r($new_wpdb);`, I get the array and I can see the values for the external database's username, password, etc. However, there's no value for `prefix` or `base_prefix`. It's just displaying the following for the prefix:

> [prefix] => [base_prefix] =>

How do I get the prefix that the external database is using?

Comment: Have you tried `$new_wpdb->get_blog_prefix()`?

Comment: @rnevius that doesn't work either. Now I think `require_once` is getting the current site's files. I need to get the external database's files. That might be my problem.

Answer (score 1):

How exactly are you connecting to the external site's WordPress?

If your code is able to `require_once wp-config.php` on the remote site then the prefix should be defined in the `$table_prefix` variable.

Or, if you can run a database query against the WordPress database (need to know the DB name or have a connection) you can run a query like `SHOW TABLES LIKE '%wp_users'` and then `$table_prefix = str_replace('wp_users', '', $result);`

Comment: The connection needs to work the same regardless of how the sites are connected. It doesn't appear that is possible in this circumstance. In the plugin I'm making, the user needs to enter in their credentials to connect to the external database, so I simply added another field to the form for them to put their prefix. I also included information in the ReadMe about how to find the prefix in case they're not sure what it is. It wasn't the solution I would have liked, but it works. Thanks for the help though.